# Image Analysis using Php

Tags: image-processing

[image: Broken bone 1]

how can I find distance between fractured bone marked in red circle ? 
By which Image segmentation method I perform difference in these images.

Comment: any user input or fully automated? define the distance. mean, max gap width area or what?

Comment: It is fully automated and I want distance in width and area

Comment: @Piglet Any solution ?